# reCAPTCHA v3 Dropping Form Submission Redirects

Tags: redirects, wordpress, forms

I have the forms on a site that I manage configured to redirect to `https://example.com/thank-you/?foo` upon submission.

The site uses Gravity Forms. My confirmation settings are like this:

[image]

When I submit the form with reCAPTCHA v3 enabled, it does not redirect, but instead brings back `https://example.com/?` with the form's default confirmation message:

> “Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.”

What's more is that the field data is also dropped:

[image]

Why would reCAPTCHA v3 cause the site to...

1. Drop the redirect to `/thank-you/?foo` and instead return `/?`
2. Fall back to the default confirmation
3. Drop data from the form fields

**Stack:**

- Nginx
- MySql
- Varnish Cache

Edit: I've submitted the form a handful of times yet see 0 requests in the reCAPTCHA v3 admin console

[image]